# Which mind control effects allow you to attack?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone, there are several cards with effects that take control of an opponent's minion such as:

- Mind Control - Take control of an enemy minion.
- Mind Control Tech - Battlecry: If your opponent has 4 or more minions, take control of one at random.

Despite the wording, these two effects work differently--Mind Control Tech allows you to immediately attack with the stolen minion, but Mind Control does not.

Which mind control effects allow you to attack immediately and which ones do not?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I didn't think the Mind Control Tech let you attack immediately. Maybe the minion you stole had Charge? The only card that does let you attack immediately (to my knowledge) is the priest ability Shadow Madness.

Comment: @dpatchery You are correct.  Only if the minion has `charge` will you be able to attack with a mind controlled minion, no matter the mechanism.  (Post as answer?)

Comment: @BlackVegetable That is at least untrue for Shadow Madness. I do admit that I may have Mind Controlled a charge minion with Mind Control Tech and gotten confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Shadow Madness, hence my somewhat incorrect comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Only those limited to one turn.**

*Mind Control* and *Mind Control Tech* both take control of a Minion permanently. This is regarded by the game's rules engine as that Minion newly joining your army and thus follows the same attacking restrictions as a Minion you summon or play from you hand. That means, unless it has **Charge**, it can't attack that turn.

*Shadow Madness* takes control of a Minion for one turn only. This would simply not do much if the Minion didn't receive **Charge** implicitly. Actually, there has been [quite a discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/1ut2yy/should_shadow_madness_mention_charge_in_the_card/) about the decision not to write it on the card (supposedly to keep it simple), but it seems *Shadow Madness* is intended (and probably handled internally) to give **Charge** to the Minion.

From a logical point of view, this exception makes sense because the card would do very little without that mechanic (notably, it would work the same way it does now with **Charge** Minions, and might get a dangerous **Taunt** Minion out of the way). Seeing as this could theoretically be intentional behaviour, though, we could well see the card reworded in the future if and when cards are released that do exactly this. For the time being, it's safe to assume that cards which take control of a Minion only for one turn give that Minion **Charge** implicitly.

Comment: Not quite the same as "coming into play under your control", as Battlecries don't trigger. Not that the info is wrong re the Charge mechanic, but it might be worth clarifying that to avoid confusion in the future!

Comment: Good point, will clarify.

Comment: Someone should try using Shadow Madness with a Warsong Commander on priest board, we would see whether the minion has charge or it is another effect. — edit: [someone did it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B3URe5Pjes), controlled minion indeed has Charge (in video commander buffs itself upon being controlled).